# Getting different output while writing to file

Tags: c, windows, file, strftime

I have written a program to keep stat of a football team. I keep the stats in a file, and record of all matches in another file called "record.txt".

In my record.txt file, the format of writing is:

> [opponent name]    [current date]

The problem I'm facing is that, sometimes I get "opponent name" "date" in a single line and sometimes date starts in a new line

Here's an image of what I'm getting
[pic of output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Avn.png)

Here's my code

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer [80];

time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
strftime (buffer,80,"%d/%m/%y",timeinfo);

/* current date acquired */
FILE *history;

history = fopen("record.txt", "a");

char opponent[10];   //opponent name

printf("Opponent Name: ");
fgets( opponent, 10, stdin);
fprintf(history, "Opponent: %s %s\n", opponent, buffer);

fclose(history);
```

Comment: Please repost the code and sample output here, not everyone's network allows pastebin or imgur.

Comment: You don't perform any check at all, `fopen()`/`fgets()` could fail and you have to check for that.

Comment: I have posted the code. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post pics

Comment: `fgets( opponent, 10, stdin);` --> `scanf("%9[^\n]", opponent);`

Comment: scanf("%9[^\n]", opponent); //any explanation on how this works? (or reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fgets(opponent, 10, stdin);
```

Note that `fgets()` reads the newline character when you press enter on `stdin`, and you are not suppressing it. If you want both the strings in same line suppress the newline like

```
size_t n = strlen(opponent);
if (n > 0 && opponent[n -1] == '\n') 
    opponent[n - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Sure, it would also be good if you suggest checking `fopen()`/`fgets()` return value. And now it's a better answer.

Comment: This works!. Thank you. Didn't know that I have to check for newline. Btw, why do I get correct format sometimes?

Comment: @JahirIslam maybe you don't press enter and press Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z instead.

Comment: @iharob no, I always press enter after inputting name.

Comment: @JahirIslam May be the input is long and it is filling up 9 characters and there is no newline character

Comment: @iharob I think this is the case. Thank you for clearing this up for me :)